# How do I get the url of the response page after I've submitted a form in mechanize?

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

Using mechanize (and python) I can go to a website, log in, find a form, fill in some answers, and submit that form. However, I don't know how I can open the "response" page - that is, the page that automatically loads once you've submitted the form.

Here's the python code:

```
br.select_form(name="simTrade")
br.form["symbolTextbox"] = "KO"
br.form["quantityTextbox"] = "10"
br.form["previewOrderButton"]

preview = br.submit()
print preview.read
```

With the above code, I can *see* what the response page holds. But I want to actually open that page and interact with it. How can I do that with mechanize? Thank you.

EDIT: So I answered my own question soon after posting this. Here's the code:

```
br.select_form(name="simTrade")
br.form["symbolTextbox"] = symbol
br.form["transactionTypeDropDown"] = [order_type]
br.form["quantityTextbox"] = amount
br.form["previewOrderButton"]

no_url = br.submit()
final = no_url.geturl()
x = br.open(final)
print x.read()
```

To get the html source code of the response page (the page that loads when you submit a form), I simply had to get the url of br.submit(). And there's a built in mechanize function for that, geturl().

Comment: I don't understand, doesn't the page remain open by default?

Comment: The page does remain open, but I want to get the url of that page and access its html via Mechanize. By doing that, I can interact with the page further.

Comment: Add your answer in the answer box `bottom of the page` . and accept it

Answer (score 1):

The OP's answer is a bit convoluted and resulted in a `AttributeError`. This worked better for me:

```
br.submit()
base_url = br.geturl()
print base_url
```

Comment: This method is now `br.get_url()` for `StatefulBrowser`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the URL of the new page and opening it isn't necessary. Once the form has been submitted the new page opens automatically and you can start interacting with it using the same mechanize browser object.

Using the original code from your question, if you wanted to submit the form and store all links on the new page in a list:

```
br.select_form(name="simTrade")
br.form["symbolTextbox"] = "KO"
br.form["quantityTextbox"] = "10"
br.form["previewOrderButton"]
br.submit()

# Here we store all links on the new page
# but we can use br do any necessary processing.
links = [link for link in br.links()]

# This will take us back to the original page with the "simTrade" form.
br.back()
```